# how to ensure that id is elected will be selected by the dropdown select

Tags: php, laravel

how to ensure that id is elected will be selected by the dropdown select ?

Controller :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data['data_article'] = Article::find($id);
    $author = Article::find($id);
    $data['tambah_author1'] = \DB::table('authors')->where('id',$author->author_id)->lists('username','id');
    $data['tambah_author2'] = \DB::table('authors')->orderBy('id','DESC')->lists('username','id');
    $data['id_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('id');
    return View::make('article.edit',$data)->with('authors',$data);
}
```

View :

```
{{ Form::select('author',($tambah_author2 + $tambah_author1),
                $id_author,
                ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

[image]

supposed to be elected early by id is "fauzi"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code suposed to be like this, it's your controller :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // Get data article for edit
    $data['data_article'] = Article::find($id);

    // Get authors data for your dropdown
    $data['authors'] = \DB::table('authors')->orderBy('id','DESC')->lists('username','id');
    return View::make('article.edit',$data);
}
```

And your view supposed to be like this :

```
{!! Form::model( $data_article, [ 'route' => 'author.update', 'method' => 'put' ] ) !!}
    {!! Form::select( 'author', $authors, $data_article->author_id, [ 'class' => 'form-control' ] ) !!}
{!! Form:close() !!}
```

**$data_article->author_id** is your author id field at article table.

**Form::model** is function to automatic insert your data to form depend on your table field, let say in your article has field : author_id

So you just nee set form like this :

```
{!! Form::select( 'author_id', $authors, null, [ 'class' => 'form-control' ] ) !!}
```

And it will automatic selected the value from your article.

Comment: why when submitted, appears MethodNotAllowedHttpException ?

Comment: @rojib what is your route method? change it to Route::put()